# C# RestSharp No Response From Get With Json Body

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

My goal is to download a file with a RestSharp GET by passing along a Json body and a security token in the header. For now, I'm just trying to get a response.

I got this code from Postman, where the GET is working (I am prompted where to save the file).

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

string responseMsg = "";
if (response.Content == "") 
    responseMsg = response.ErrorMessage
else
    responseMsg = response.Content
return responseMsg;
```

The only response that I'm getting is the ErrorException "**HTTP verb GET does not support body**".

So I believe there is an issue with my logic, not my Json or token. Does anything in my code look incorrect?

Application framework: .Net 4.8

RestSharp version: 106.15.0

Thanks.

Edit:

As mentioned below, a GET request with a body parameter is invalid. After removing the the json body, the request is now working.

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

In the case of my application, the unique identifier was appended to the endpoint, so only the security token was needed as a header.

Comment: what happens when you try to call this api from Postman.? GET APIs are not supposed to have request body. That's why you are getting this error. If the API is expecting a request body it should be changed to POST or PUT.

Comment: And if it's supposed to be a GET API, then you need to change from a request body to request parameters. Can you show the REST API you're trying to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GET requests cannot have bodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), or rather, they can, but that behaviour is not defined and so some implementations will reject the request entirely. It [appears](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1330) that RestSharp also intentionally does not support GET requests with bodies for the same reason. According to that thread, .NET itself may support them, so you might wish to try that if it's absolutely necessary.

Whether or not you *should* do that might come under the umbrella of personal opinion, however with that in mind I would caution against doing things outside of the specification, because any updates to libraries or frameworks have no guarantee of consistency of behaviour when they're being used out of spec. If this is an API you have control over, you should consider bringing it in-spec. If it's not, you should consider contacting the developer to have them look into it.

Comment: Although your answer is not incorrect, it would be more helpful to show how the API should be called using GET with parameters